# Extracting Names That Has Specific Word

Tags: sql

I would like to extract rows that has **'venture'** in the **Name Column** as shown below.

[image]

The following SQL code is used to get that result

```
CASE
  WHEN summary.cust_analysis.Name LIKE '%VENTURE%'
```

However, how can I extract **only** the first row which has 'Venture' as a word instead of having it as a part of a word like Bonaventure?

If I remove the '%' from the SQL code non of the rows will get extracted.

Appreciate all your help. Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you are on SQL Server, isn't it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some products have their own functions that could be convenient here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN summary.cust_analysis.Name LIKE '% VENTURE %'
```

or

```
CASE WHEN summary.cust_analysis.Name LIKE '% VENTURE %'
    OR summary.cust_analysis.Name LIKE '% VENTURE' 
    OR summary.cust_analysis.Name LIKE 'VENTURE %' 
    OR summary.cust_analysis.Name = 'VENTURE'
```

with due concern for upper/lower case presumably too

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server you can use `Regular Expressions`.

So you can match entire word followed or preceded by another symbols like dot or comma:

```
CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%[^A-Z]Venture[^A-Z]%'
    OR Name LIKE 'Venture[^A-Z]%'
    OR Name LIKE '%[^A-Z]Venture'
    OR Name = 'Venture'
```

This will match `,Venture`, `Venture.`, `Venture:`

[More info here](https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to prepend and postpend the string with spaces:

```
where concat(' ', summary.cust_analysis.Name, ' ') like '% VENTURE %'
```

You can use the same logic in a `CASE` expression:

```
select (case when concat(' ', summary.cust_analysis.Name, ' ') like '% VENTURE %' 
             then 'VENTURE'
        end)
```

Note:  This uses the `CONCAT()` function for string concatenation.  The SQL Standard operator is `||` and some databases have other methods.